# mistically, NODE_ENV(or any other custom env variable) is undefined in my project

Tags: node.js

I faced this problem for the first time in my life - 
even though I set NODE_ENV(tried others - also does not work) - I have these variables undefined.

[image: example]

How can I fix that?

I'm using node 7.7.3, npm 4.1.2, Mac OS X El Captain

Thanks in advance

Comment: @AndrewLi it's in undefined not just in browser(in my angular app) - it is undefined even in webpack.config.js, so on nodejs side

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your command `NODE_ENV` related to `rm`, not to `webpack`. To fix that insert `NODE_ENV` before webpack:

```
rm -rf ./dist/ && NODE_ENV=development webpack --watch --progress
```

Comment: oh.. what a dumb mistake I've made. thank you, you are right